# Is there a way I can write this Haskell code in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, partial-application

I'm going through a few functional programming languages, learning things of interest, and I'm looking at Scala now. What I'm trying to do is figure out the simplest way to write a function called `double` which take one argument and doubles it. What I've come up with so far is:

```
def double = (x:Int) => x*2
```

or

```
def double(x:Int) = x*2
```

This works, but I'm looking for the *simplest* way. In Haskell, I could simply do this:

```
double = (*2)
```

Because it's a partially applied function, there's no need to name the variable or specify any types (I'm sure the `*` function takes care of that). Is there a similar way to do this using Scala? I've tried a few, especially using `_` instead of `x`, but none seemed to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
val double = (_: Int) * 2
```

**Note** Here `double` is a `Function` rather than a `method`. In your first example, you have defined a `method` named `double` with return type of `Function`. In your second example, your just have defined a `method`.
`Function` is different from `method` in Scala.

In case the compiler can get the type information, we can write the `Function` even simple:

```
scala> def apply(n: Int, f: Int => Int) = f(n)
apply: (n: Int, f: Int => Int)Int

scala> apply(10, 2*)
res1: Int = 20

scala> apply(10, 100+)
res2: Int = 110
```

Comment: "Function is different from method in Scala." A seemingly very important fact that I was clueless of. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Whoa. I never knew we could pass `2*` that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest Way to write it is

```
*2
```

Comment: How can this be set to a val? I tried `val double = *2`, but it didn't like that.

Comment: No, you don't write `val double = ` at all, just * 2 where you need it. It means the same, is directly understandable and avoids confusion with java.lang.Double and such.